# Add rows out of column averages conditional to other column values

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the average values of the last two columns conditional to the same value in column year and add them as rows.

Initial data:

```
sector <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
year <- c(1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982)
value1 <- c(20,21,22,24,25,21,25,27,25)
value2 <- c(98,95,85,78,84,86,85,82,83)
df <- data.frame(sector, year, value1, value2)
```

the end result would be this

```
sector <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3, "average1980", "average1981", "average1982")
year <- c(1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982)
value1 <- c(20,21,22,24,25,21,25,27,25, 23,24.33,22.667)
value2 <- c(98,95,85,78,84,86,85,82,83,87,88,84.667)
df44 <- data.frame(sector, year, value1, value2)
```

I am not sure at all how to start. I am using dplyr and playing with mutate and summarise and then bind_rowd. But I can't figure it out...

here an attempt:

```
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(value1 = mean(value1),
            value2 = mean(value2)) %>%
  mutate(sector = paste0("average", year)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
              mutate(sector = as.character(sector))) %>%
  arrange(year, sector, sector != "year")
```

but it gives me a new column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are on the right path. This will fihish what you started

```
library(tidyverse)

sector <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
year <- c(1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982)
value1 <- c(20,21,22,24,25,21,25,27,25)
value2 <- c(98,95,85,78,84,86,85,82,83)
df <- data.frame(sector, year, value1, value2)



new.df=df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(value1 = mean(value1),
            value2 = mean(value2)) %>%
  mutate(sector = paste0("average", year)) %>% 
  relocate(sector)

final.df=rbind(df,new.df)
```

But I dont think is a good idea to add the final rows... maybe its better, or more tidy, to keep it as a separate dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I got your desired output by tweaking your original code some. This will create a new dataframe and leave your original alone. I changed your `arrange()` line so that it is only sorting on sector. And then the sector column is moved back to the first column.

```
sector <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
year <- c(1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982,1980,1981,1982)
value1 <- c(20,21,22,24,25,21,25,27,25)
value2 <- c(98,95,85,78,84,86,85,82,83)
df <- data.frame(sector, year, value1, value2)

library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(value1 = mean(value1),
              value2 = mean(value2)) %>%
    mutate(sector = paste0("average", year)) %>%
    bind_rows(df %>%
                  mutate(sector = as.character(sector))) %>%
    arrange(sector) %>%
    relocate(sector)

df1
```